# Open Windows Explorer directory, select a specific file (in Delphi)

Tags: delphi, explorer

I have a procedure to open a folder in Windows Explorer that gets passed a directory path:

```
procedure TfrmAbout.ShowFolder(strFolder: string);
begin
   ShellExecute(Application.Handle,PChar('explore'),PChar(strFolder),nil,nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Is there a way to also pass this a file name (either the full file name path or just the name + extension) and have the folder open in Windows Explorer but also be highlighted/selected? The location I am going to has many files and I need to then manipulate that file in Windows.

Comment: Using the method as answered by Andreas Rejbrand below, I am hitting dead ends with strange activity, I'm on Win7 Pro 32bit and sometimes when using this, it either opens the directory but doesn't highlight the file, or it opens some out of the ordinary directory and highlights something completely irrelevant. For example, just now I used it to select a file, but it opened my personal user folder and highlighted "My Documents" folder, when the file I was directing it to isn't even on the same hard drive.

Comment: I just noticed a trend with this issue, it happens when there are certain characters in the filename, for example a comma, which throws off the command

Comment: NOTE: My above issue was resolved with an update by Andreas including another more specific and reliable solution.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`/select` flag](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457) when you call `explorer.exe`:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'explorer.exe', '/select,C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe', nil,
  SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

A somewhat more fancy (and perhaps also more reliable) approach (`uses ShellAPI, ShlObj`):

```
const
  OFASI_EDIT = $0001;
  OFASI_OPENDESKTOP = $0002;

{$IFDEF UNICODE}
function ILCreateFromPath(pszPath: PChar): PItemIDList stdcall; external shell32
  name 'ILCreateFromPathW';
{$ELSE}
function ILCreateFromPath(pszPath: PChar): PItemIDList stdcall; external shell32
  name 'ILCreateFromPathA';
{$ENDIF}
procedure ILFree(pidl: PItemIDList) stdcall; external shell32;
function SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidlFolder: PItemIDList; cidl: Cardinal;
  apidl: pointer; dwFlags: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall; external shell32;

function OpenFolderAndSelectFile(const FileName: string): boolean;
var
  IIDL: PItemIDList;
begin
  result := false;
  IIDL := ILCreateFromPath(PChar(FileName));
  if IIDL <> nil then
    try
      result := SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(IIDL, 0, nil, 0) = S_OK;
    finally
      ILFree(IIDL);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: string passed to the parameter must be null terminated is it?

Comment: Yes, the compiler makes sure that there are null terminators.

Comment: Please note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291793/selecting-file-in-windows-explorers-does-not-always-work?rq=1 This doesn't always work, and I in fact just witnessed it not working myself.

Comment: I wish this wasn't closed as a duplicate because as I say in my comment in the question above, the other accepted answer is in C++ and uses a different mechanism than this. I'd like to see if someone can answer this question using that code converted to Delphi, because I cannot figure out how to re-write it.

Comment: @JerryDodge: I implemented that for you.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, the "fancy approach" is much, much, much more reliable.

Comment: @Jerry: Yeah, I suppose this API function was added for a reason.

Comment: For those that are using Delphi XE and up: you don't have to declare ILCreateFromPath & co.

Comment: This is VERY SLOW. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @user1580348: Shouldn't be slow. Should take less than a second. (So compared to multiplying two floating-point numbers, of course, is it extremely slow, but it involves the shell and shell extensions might be involved. That's quite heavy. But it shouldn't be slower than opening a new Explorer window with Win+E or opening an Open dialog box in Notepad.) If it takes several seconds, maybe you have some troublesome shell extension?

Comment: I wrote a program where a user could open/select dozens of different files.  I do **not** want `explorer.exe` to be run dozens of times.  This code does not instantiate a new instance of `explorer.exe`.  Bravo!

Comment: Would be nice if this could be extended to select multiple files

Answer (score 2):

The answers at [delphi.lonzu.net](http://delphi.longzu.net/viewthread.php?tid=48280&extra=page%3D67) and [swissdelphicenter](https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=484) offer a simpler solution to this. I've only tested it on Windows 10, 1909,, but the gist of it is:

```
uses ShellApi, ...
...
var
   FileName : TFileName;
begin
  FileName := 'c:\temp\somefile.html';

  ShellExecute(Handle, 'OPEN', 
    pchar('explorer.exe'), 
    pchar('/select, "' + FileName + '"'), 
    nil, 
    SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

This is simple and easy to use. Whether it works with older versions of Windows, I don't know.

Comment: It works even back in Windows XP, so that's probably fine for most.

Comment: I created an empty unit, and need more uses like Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, Forms,