# ShellExecute open folder/file and scroll to selected

Tags: delphi, windows-10

greetings, first question here. I use this Delphi 10.3 code to call Windows 10 Explorer with a file selected:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'OPEN', pchar('explorer.exe'), pchar('/select, "' + myfile + '"'), nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

It works fine, no problems. The only thing is that Explorer does not scroll the window to make the selected file visible. This is not a problem with a few files, but if the folder contains hundreds of files finding the one selected is difficult and not friendly to my end users.

Is there a better function that I could call from Delphi to force Windows Explorer to scroll to the selected file so it becomes visible?

Thank you.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300999/open-windows-explorer-directory-select-a-specific-file-in-delphi answer your question?

Comment: Indeed it does. Thank You!. How do I mark the question as answered by you?

Comment: Great! I can do that for you by marking this question as a duplicate of the old one.

Comment: Thank you, Andreas, best regards.